# c++ .eof. Last value of file not read

Tags: c++, arrays, eof

I am trying to read all of the integers from a file (can be up to 100 ints) into an array, and print out the numbers entered, and how many numbers were entered. I am having trouble with ".eof". No matter what I try, the last value in the input file is not read. Can somebody please tell me what the problem is? Here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
    {

    int bubble[100];
    int s = 0;
    int count = 0;
    string fileName;

    //int i = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) bubble[i] = 0;

    cout << "Enter the name of a file of integers to be sorted " << endl;
    cin >> fileName;


   ifstream myfile (fileName);
    myfile >> s;
    //bubble[0] = s;



    while (! myfile.eof() )  //while the end of file is not reached
    {

        //myfile >> s;
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            //myfile >> s;
            if(! myfile.eof())
            {
                bubble[i] = s;
                myfile >> s;
            }
            else
            {
                bubble[i] = -1;
            } 
        } 



        //i++;
    }

    myfile.close();


    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        if(bubble[i] != -1)
        {
            count ++;
        }
    }

   // cout << count;

    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if(bubble[i] != -1)
    {


        if((i % 10 == 9) || (i== count-1))
        {
            cout << setw(4) << bubble[i] << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << setw(4) << bubble[i] << " ";
        }

        //count ++;
    }

    }

    cout << "\n\nNumber of values in the input file: " << count << endl;

return 0;
}
```

input:
100 94 59 83 7 11 92 76 37 89 74 59 65 79 49 89 89 75 64 82 15 74 82 68 92 61 33 95 91 82 89 64 43 93 86 65 72 40 42 90 81 62 90 89 35 81 48 33 94 81 76 86 67 70 100 80 83 78 96 58

output:
Enter the name of a file of integers to be sorted 
bubble_input.txt
 100   94   59   83    7   11   92   76   37   89
  74   59   65   79   49   89   89   75   64   82
  15   74   82   68   92   61   33   95   91   82
  89   64   43   93   86   65   72   40   42   90
  81   62   90   89   35   81   48   33   94   81
  76   86   67   70  100   80   83   78   96

Number of values in the input file: 59

(should be 60, and 58 should be in the last spot)

Thank you for any help!

Comment: try putting whitespace after last item

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do in your code is (excuse the pseudo-pseudo code):

```
save value of `s` in `bubble[i]`
read in an integer, saving it in the variable `s`,
repeat as long as we have something on the input
```

This way when you reach end of file, the last variable is still only stored in `s`, you don't copy it over to `bubble[i]`. Simply save it in the array straight away, should solve your problem.

Edit - what I also noticed - the while loop doesn't work like an if. If the file has more than 100 integers, you will overwrite the first 100 with the numbers that follow (and possibly -1s).

Comment: How would I do it all at once. It keeps giving me errors when I try this

Comment: Something in the lines of `myfile >> bubble[i];`. Or just swap the 2 lines inside of the `if` body.